# Get viewController reference to shared code behind file

Tags: ios, swift

I've just started developing apps for iOS and I have a problem that I can't figure out atm.

My app will contain two viewControllers, both of them will have one label each and I want the code behind (one single file) to do the same calculation but with two different numbers depending on which viewController is shown.

For example: The code behind should calculate 1 * X, where X is either 1 for the first view or 2 for the second view. (And print the sum)

So, is there anyway I can get the reference of which view I'm (the user) at?
Or do I have to create two files for code behind with the same code, just the one number different?

Storyboard:
[image]

What I want to achieve in pseudo:

```
if viewController == 1
    label1.text = 1
else if viewController == 2
    label2.text = 2
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: how do you show those views? It would be helpfull see some code :)

Comment: At this point I don't have any code. I've just created two views using drag and drop.

Comment: What does it mean for you to "be at a view"?

Comment: The screen containing Label1 is one view and the one containing Label2 is my second. Guess "view" is not the correct word. So when the user sees label1, I want the code behind to do some calculations.

Comment: I guess I used the words all wrong. When I say viewController I mean the code behind and "view" is actually the viewController

Comment: I rewrote the question, don't know if that helps or if I did it even worse.

Answer (score 0):

IMO the best option would be to have one view controller (in storyboard too) and just two views as outlets and swap them (hide/show).

But you can distinguish between those views for example by tag property of UIView.

[image: tag property in storyboard]

Comment: If you have connected view with an outlet in view controller jut like that: `view.tag`

Comment: How to create an outlet connection: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_connections/chapters/CreatingOutlet.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014227-CH15-SW1

Comment: This looks promising, I'll try and let you know. Thank you!

Comment: What if I have 18 viewControllers in a flow of a navigation controller (forward button using push). How to tell which view controller user's at?

Comment: ViewController has methods viewDidAppear and ViewDidDisappear that you can override (but remember calling super). Between those calls user is at particular view controller.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79460/discussion-between-kostek-and-johan-magnusson).